# What are the different between stream_socket_* and socket in php?

Tags: php, sockets

I know the stream_socket_* is base on socket,but I don't know they use case.

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you see as a problem.  At the moment it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9760548/3345375